# Seam with Postgresql. NullPointerException until I drop and re-create table

Tags: seam

On local dev environment.  Periodically (a few times per day) my Client table seems to get 'corrupted' and my ClientList.xhtml page crashes with a cryptic null pointer exception.  It sometimes happens when I edit a client, but I don't know how exactly to recreate the problem.  I fix it by dropping and recreating the table.  My question is what could be happening that is fixed by dropping and recreating the table?

setup is Seam 2 and postgresql 9.0.4.  Basic seam-gen generated crud forms.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the following so we can help:

- Stack trace for the NullPointerException
- Source code for the Client entity
- Data from the problem Client record (if you know it)

Comment: I can no longer recreate this.  The client entity has changed and the problem seems to have gone away through magic and time.